# Invalid characters returning from rest-client call

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

Here is my Ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-

(...)

begin
    response = RestClient.post props['server']['host'] + post_to + "?auth=" + props['server']['auth'],
            model_name => o, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
rescue => e
    response = e.response
end

if response.code != 201
    puts "Erro ao salvar #{model_name} #{o[descriptor]}: " + response.to_str
end
```

It's working pretty well, however, when my model has some invalid field, my returning message in `response.to_str` that is supposed to be:

```
"{"kind":["Só é permitido uma matriz por domínio."]}"
```

is printed as:

```
"{"kind":["S\u00f3 \u00e9 permitido uma matriz por dom\u00ednio."]}"
```

I already checked `response.headers`, the charset returned is indeed `utf-8`.

If I try:

```
if response.code != 201
    puts "{\"kind\":[\"S\u00f3 \u00e9 permitido uma matriz por dom\u00ednio.\"]}"
    puts "{\"kind\":[\"Só é permitido uma matriz por domínio.\"]}"
    puts response.to_str
end
```

The first and the second output are printed correctly, but the third one is not. Why!?

I'm using Ubuntu and calling this script from gnome terminal.

Comment: It looks like this is not a ruby-side issue. Your REST service is likely encodes utf with double slashes or smth like that. Woukld you examine the pure REST-answer with kinda `Firebug`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, mudasobwa, your tip helped me solve this out.

The problem was that I am receiving a JSON object from the server:

```
"kind":["Só é permitido uma matriz por domínio."]
```

and just printing it seems not to be the correct approach. I think it's because my Ruby code is parsing this JSON as an Array and printing it. If I do this:

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'yaml'
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

# (...)

if response.code != 201
    obj = JSON.parse(response.to_str)
    puts "Erro ao salvar #{model_name} #{o[descriptor]}: " + obj.to_s
end
```

The problem gets solved.